# Plot countour of two distributions with different colormaps

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I want to plot the `contourf` of two distributions, distinguishing them with different colors, and not having "one on top of another" but rather have the higher points on top of the lower points

Toy example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = np.zeros((len(y), len(x), 2))
Z[:,:,0] = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z[:,:,1] = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
```

OK let's plot them:

```
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z[:,:,0], cmap='Reds', alpha=0.6)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z[:,:,1], cmaps='Blues', alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Not really what I want, since the second plot is on top of the first.
So I tried taking the max of the distributions along the second axis

```
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(X, Y, np.max(Z, axis=2),alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now they look as I want, but I mixed them, so I'm unable to plot them in different colors (red vs blue)

I can use argmax to know which plot gave me the maxima, and I could create a matrix of index, but I don't know how to tell countourf to use this matrix to determine the colormap to be used.

How can I keep the colors and not having them sitting on top of each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you may mask both contours mutually exclusively.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = np.zeros((len(y), len(x), 2))
Z[:,:,0] = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z[:,:,1] = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
mask = Z[:,:,0] > Z[:,:,1]
plt.figure()
plt.contourf(X, Y, np.ma.array(Z[:,:,0], mask=~mask), cmap='Reds', 
             alpha=0.6)
plt.contourf(X, Y, np.ma.array(Z[:,:,1], mask=mask), cmap='Blues', 
             alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What's the white part? If one plot takes the mask and the other the complementary such zone shouldn't exist.

Comment: Sure it exists, since every grid point is either part of the contour or the other,not both.

Comment: Increasing the resolution from 0.1 to 0.01 makes the white zone not noticeable. But still not exactly what I want. Since I have some transparency I would like both distributions to be seen everywhere, just not one on top of the other.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki you said: *Since I have some transparency I would like both distributions to be seen everywhere, just not one on top of the other* I've read this sentence several times and can't figure out what it means. Can you explain further, maybe linking to some examples? Do you want separate axes?

Comment: I actually achieved more a less what I wanted, by using 4 contours as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested, then putting the "bottom" contours with a low alpha and the top ones with a high alpha value.